# Почему картинки на deploy не отображаются?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github-pages, deploy

Залил проект для тестов на github pages, открыл, отображается только 1 картинка, так же в папке build почему-то только эта 1 картинка переместилась в папку media, остальные просто в папку imgs. Локально же всё работало до замены BrowserRouter на HashRouter и непосредственно дэплоя. Даже после того, как я поменял пути всех остальных картинок на подобие той, что отображается - не помогло. Стоит учесть, что работает только фото находящееся в стилях css, остальные же находятся внутри разных компонентов.

Так выглядит файловая структура

[image]

В стилях всё работает:

```
background: url(/public/imgs/main-screen__bgc.jpg);
```

А в компоненте уже перепробовал все пути, не работает:

```
          <div className={cl.social__container}>
            <a href='https://www.youtube.com'>
                <SocialItem link='/imgs/youtube_comp.svg'/>
            </a>
            <a href='https://www.facebook.com'>
                <SocialItem link='../imgs/facebook_comp.svg'/>
            </a>
            <a href='https://www.instagram.com'>
                <SocialItem link='../public/imgs/instagram_comp.svg'/>
            </a>
         </div>
         <img src="/public/imgs/logo_computer.svg" alt="Logo"/>
```

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: ../../public/imgs/instagram_comp.svg

Comment: А вообще в public не кладут img, которые используются в компонентах. Они туда должны сами перекладываться webpack ом или другим сборщиком. И он же перепишет все пути как надо. Кладите картинки внутрь папки src. Пускай будут копии. Потом научитесь пользоваться сборщиком...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в gh-pages сборке пути строятся так:

```
<img src="/название репозитория/imgs/..." />
```

но лучше воспользоваться бандлером и импортировать изображения в компоненты, как писали в комментах, тогда не будет проблем с путями. вот пример:

```
import photo from './photos/lmK8L8nRkqk.jpg';

export default function App() {
  return <img src={photo} alt="" />;
}
```